# Unable to load JS and CSS in Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a problem trying to deploy Google Cloud App Engine. I am trying to deploy angular 6 application in google cloud but found out that those JS and CSS that I have added in the assets folder was not loaded. Below the error I have encountered:

```
GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/main-headlinev2.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:17 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/node_modules/smartmenus/src/jquery.smartmenus.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:19 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:21 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/jquery.smartmenus.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:22 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/node_modules/sticky-kit/dist/sticky-kit.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:20 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:32 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:34 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/animated-headline.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:33 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:35 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:36 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/htmlTag.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:38 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/portfoilo-main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:37 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/animate.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:41 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/dist/royAngularProjectv/assets/css/popup.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:42 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/common.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:114 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/styles.44d3eb7da3544ddab0d2.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:23 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:24 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/formFilling.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:25 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/src/assets/js/imagesloaded.min.js?ver=3.2.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:26 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:29 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/contactUs.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:307 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/polyfills.8d49802c7c9430759c40.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:27 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/general.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:28 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:18 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/main-headlinev2.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
2tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:307 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/scripts.66445d745b5a386b2ba7.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:19 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:20 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:21 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/jquery.smartmenus.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:22 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/node_modules/sticky-kit/dist/sticky-kit.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:23 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:24 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/formFilling.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:25 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/src/assets/js/imagesloaded.min.js?ver=3.2.0 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:26 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:27 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/general.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:28 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:29 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/js/contactUs.js 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:34 Active resource loading counts reached a per-frame limit while the tab was in background. Network requests will be delayed until a previous loading finishes, or the tab is brought to the foreground. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5527160148197376 for more details
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:32 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:35 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:36 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/htmlTag.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:33 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:34 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/animated-headline.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:41 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/dist/royAngularProjectv/assets/css/popup.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:37 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/animate.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:38 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/portfoilo-main.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:42 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/assets/css/common.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/:114 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/styles.44d3eb7da3544ddab0d2.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
4(index):307 GET http://tidy-etching-224411.appspot.com/runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

my app.yaml

```
#service: stage
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files:
- ^(?!dist)  # Skip any files not in the dist folder

handlers:
# Routing for bundles to serve directly
- url: /((?:runtime|main|polyfills|styles|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/royAngularProjectv/\1
  upload: dist/royAngularProjectv/.*

# Routing for bundle maps to serve directly
- url: /((?:runtime|main|polyfills|styles|vendor)\.[a-z0-9]+\.js\.map)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/royAngularProjectv/\1
  upload: dist/royAngularProjectv/.*

# Routing for a prod styles.bundle.css to serve directly
- url: /(styles\.[a-z0-9]+\.css)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/my-app/\1
  upload: dist/my-app/.*

# Routing for typedoc, assets, and favicon.ico to serve directly
- url: /((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/my-app/\1
  upload: dist/my-app/.*

# Routing for service worker files serve directly
- url: /(manifest\.json|ngsw\.json|ngsw-worker\.js|safety-worker\.js|worker-basic\.min\.js|ngsw_worker\.es6\.js\.map)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/royAngularProjectv/\1
  upload: dist/royAngularProjectv/.*

# Any other requests are routed to index.html for angular to handle so we don't need hash URLs
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/royAngularProjectv/index.html
  upload: dist/royAngularProjectv/index\.html
  http_headers:
    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

and last but not least my index.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>Roy Yip's Portfoilo using Angular 6</title>
             <!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->

             <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>-->
             <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>-->
             <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
             <script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
             <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
             <script src='/node_modules/smartmenus/src/jquery.smartmenus.js'></script> 
             <script src='assets/js/main-headlinev2.js'></script>
             <script src='/src/assets/css/bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
             <script src='/src/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js'></script>
             <script src='/src/assets/js/jquery.smartmenus.min.js'></script> 
             <script src='/node_modules/sticky-kit/dist/sticky-kit.min.js'></script>
            <script src='/src/assets/js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js'></script>
            <script src='/src/assets/js/formFilling.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='/src/assets/js/imagesloaded.min.js?ver=3.2.0'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='/node_modules/masonry-layout/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js'></script>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='/src/assets/js/general.js'></script>
            <script src="/src/assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/src/assets/js/contactUs.js"></script>

             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" defer>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/style.css">
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/animated-headline.css">
             <link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css' href='/src/assets/css/bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='/src/assets/css/htmlTag.css' />
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/animate.css">  
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/portfoilo-main.css"/>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/htmlTag.css"/>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/assets/css/popup.css"/>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href='/src/assets/css/common.css' />
        <!--for main page-->

        <!--for Portfolio page-->
        <!--<link rel='stylesheet' id='mauer-stills-stylesheet-css'  href='/assets/stylePaulForPort.css' type='text/css' media='all' />-->

       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">-->

       <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>-->

        <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
        <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
        <!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->

         <!--<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css' href='/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />-->

     <!--<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css' href='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-content/themes/mauer-stills/includes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.9.6' type='text/css' media='all' />-->
         <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-content/themes/mauer-stills/includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>-->
    <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>-->
    <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2b'></script>-->
    <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-content/themes/mauer-stills/includes/placeholdersJS/placeholders.jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>-->
    <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-content/themes/mauer-stills/js/general.js?ver=1.1'></script>-->

    <!--Load JavaScript-->                                   
    <!-- <script src='js/imagesloaded.pkgd.js'></script>         -->
    <!-- <script src='js/isotope.pkgd.js'></script>         -->
    <!-- <script src='js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.0-packed.js'></script> -->
    <!-- <script src='js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script> -->
    <!-- <script src='js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js'></script> -->
    <!-- <script src='js/jquery.easing.1.3.js'></script> -->
    <!-- <script src='js/main-headline.js'></script> -->
        <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css"> -->
        <!-- Bootstrap  -->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">-->
        <!-- Flexslider  -->
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css"> -->
        <!-- Theme style  -->

        <!-- Modernizr JS -->

        <!--<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->


         <style type="text/css">


            #lightbox .modal-content {
                display: inline-block;
                text-align: center;   
            }

            #lightbox .close {
                opacity: 1;
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
                padding: 5px 8px;
                border-radius: 30px;
                border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
                position: absolute;
                top: -15px;
                right: -55px;

                z-index:1032;
            }
        </style>


        <base href="/">

    </head>

    <body>
        <app-root class="wrapper"></app-root>

        <div id="lightbox" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <button type="button" class="close hidden" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            //$.noConflict();
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
                    theme: "minimal"
                });

                $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                    $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
                    $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
                    $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
                });

                 $("#wrapper").click(function() {
                    $(".menu").toggleClass("close");
                });



            });


        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          var $lightbox = $('#lightbox');


          $('[data-target="#lightbox"]').on('click', function(event) {
              var $img = $(this).find('img'), 
      src = $img.attr('src'),
            //src = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/ooomf-com-files/lqCNpAk3SCm0bdyd5aA0_IMG_4060_1%20copy.jpg',
                  alt = $img.attr('alt'),
             id = $img.attr('id'),
                  css = {
                      'maxWidth': $(window).width() - 100,
                      'maxHeight': $(window).height() - 100
                  };

            if (id=='Taxi_cal')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/screenshot_android_studio.jpg';

            }
            else if (id=='Taxi_cal_por')
            {
                src="/src/assets/images/Mobile_Portrait.png";

            }
            else if (id=='NS_photo')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/NS_photo.jpg';

            }
            else if (id=='NCS_collages')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/NCS_collages(1440x810).jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='gold_swim')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/Gold_swimming.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='sliver_swim')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/Sliver_swimming.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='broze_swim')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/Broze_Swimming.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='kayking')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/Kayking.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='ncc_course')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/NCC_course_cert.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='ncc_badge')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/Army_NCC_badge.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='ns_cert')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/NS_cert.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='ns_compelites')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/NS_compelites.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='touch_youth')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/Touch_Youth.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='TP_voulteer')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/TP_voulteering.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='yog_cert')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/achievement_img/YOG_cert.jpg';
            }
            else if (id=='staff_wellence_mobile')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/wireframe(Staff wellence)(login mobile).png';
            }
            else if (id=='staff_wellence_tab')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/wireframe(Staff wellence)(login table).png';

            }
            else if (id=='staff_wellence_desk')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/wireframe(Staff wellence).png';
            }

            else if (id=='staff_wellence_chart')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/wireframe(Staff wellence)(chart page).png';

            }

            else if (id=='staff_wellence_main')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/wireframe(Staff wellence)(main page).png';
            }

            else if (id=='android_studio')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/Android_Studio.png';
            }

            else if (id=='mobile_faq')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/Mobile_Portrait_FAQ.png';

            }
            else if (id=='mobile_popup')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/Mobile_Portrait_pop_up.png';

            }
            else if (id=='mobile_port')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/Mobile_Portrait.png';

            }
            else if (id=='Website_portfolio')
            {
                src='/src/assets/images/WebsitePortfolio.JPG'
            }


              $lightbox.find('.close').addClass('hidden');
              $lightbox.find('img').attr('src', src);
              $lightbox.find('img').attr('alt', alt);
              $lightbox.find('img').css(css);
          });

          $lightbox.on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
              var $img = $lightbox.find('img');

              $lightbox.find('.modal-dialog').css({'width': $img.width()});
              $lightbox.find('.close').removeClass('hidden');
          });
      });
      </script>



    <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-content/themes/mauer-stills/includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-includes/js/imagesloaded.min.js?ver=3.2.0'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-includes/js/masonry.min.js?ver=3.3.2'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.masonry.min.js?ver=3.1.2b'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-content/themes/mauer-stills/includes/placeholdersJS/placeholders.jquery.min.js?ver=4.9.6'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://stills.mauer.co/wp-content/themes/mauer-stills/js/general.js?ver=1.1'></script>-->

    </body>

    </html>
```

May I know what to do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I see an error in the url configuration of the app.yaml

```
((?:assets|docs)/.*|favicon\.ico)
```

I think it should be

```
((?:assets|docs)\.*|favicon\.ico)
```

I also tried to replicate your problem but without been able to see the directories you are trying to upload, I have not found the exact issue you’re facing.

I would recommend you to start in a simpler manner, just upload all the files in the directory when the URL is first accessed, like this:

```
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: dist/royAngularProjectv/\1
  upload: dist/royAngularProjectv/.*
```

Once done that, you can try to refine the URL handler in the app.yaml.

You can also use [static_dir](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers) which takes everything after the end of the matched url pattern and appends it to [static_dir](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/serving-static-files#configuring_the_app_to_use_static_files) to form the full path to the requested file. You can find a simple example on Serving Static Files